# Upgrading IIS7 to IIS8

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-7.5, iis-8

We have planned to upgrade our IIS to version 8, however I'm facing a problem in upgrading IIS7.  Here is a snap of my IIS, which seems to be acting weird.

[image]

1) It is showing 3 different version numbers,

```
version 7  
version 6.1  
version 7.5.7600.16385
```

this is really confusing and I have no idea about this behavior.

2) From **where can I find the options to upgrade it to latest version of 8**

> **OS - Windows Server 2008 R2**

Please share your suggestions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have `7.5.7600.16385`. `6.1` Refers to your version of Windows and `7` refers to a generic version. It's not 6 or 8, but rather 7. Of your IIS 7, you're running the `7.5.7600.16385` version. You would most likely need to upgrade to Server 2012 to run IIS8. Below is a chart of the different OS Versions and their supporting IIS version.

```
Windows XP - IIS 5.1
Server 2003 - IIS 6
Server 2008 - IIS 7
Server 2008 R2 - IIS 7.5
Server 2012 - IIS 8
```

Comment: This confused a lot.  Thanks for your clarification.  However why it is not showing IIS 7.5 in UI?  any reason you could share?

Comment: @Praveen it's common for Microsoft and even common practice for software in general to use/issue version numbers in this way. For example version 7.x is an iteration of version 7. This means the version 7.x has some improvements, modifications, &/or adaptations compared to version 7.0 for example. However, version 7.x or even 7.x.x is still version 7. That's to say it isn't version 8! Take the iPhone for example, this is probably the World's most well known versioning system.

Comment: The iPhone 4s is different from iPhone 4, but it's still significantly based on the iPhone 4, it's certainly not the iPhone 5 which is significantly different from the iPhone 4 & 4s (think of it as 4.5).

Answer (score 2):

IIS 8 is part of Windows 8 and Server 2012. Because you still use 2008 R2, you still have the IIS 7.5.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it means I can't/don't need to upgrade to IIS8 right?

Comment: you can only upgrade to IIS8(.5) if you update to Server 2012(R2).